# Logistic regression curve not centered with my data

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I am doing a school project with logistic regression for binary classification and I am getting pretty bad results (accuracy around 50%). I had to do this classification from scratch so I am worried there is a problem with my implementation.

I fit a model with a single predictor and plotted the resulting logistic curve and noticed that it was centered around 0, outside the range of my data (the predictor ranges from 50 - 90) . Because of this, only the asymptote of the logistic curve is within the range of my data and therefore is classifying all examples into the same class.

I thought that using an intercept weight would address this problem but in my case it has not. I also thought about normalizing my data and centering it around 0 but I was hoping there would be a more direct approach.

Any suggestions?

EDIT - Here is my implementation

```
class LogisticRegression:                                                    

def __init__(self, alpha, iters, intercept=True):                        
    self.alpha = alpha                                                   
    self.iters = iters                                                   
    self.weights = None                                                  
    self.intercept = intercept                                           

def sigmoid(self, z):                                                    
    return 1.0 / (1 + np.exp(-z))                                        

def add_intercept(self, X):                                              
    intercept = np.ones((X.shape[0], 1))                                 
    return np.concatenate((intercept, X), axis=1)                        

def cost(self, h, y):                                                    
    return (-y * np.log(h) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h)).mean()             

def fit(self, X, y):                                                     

    if self.intercept:                                                   
        X = self.add_intercept(X)                                        

    self.weights = np.zeros(X.shape[1])                                  

    for i in range(self.iters):                                          
        z = np.dot(X, self.weights)                                      
        h = self.sigmoid(z)                                              
        gradient = np.dot(X.T, (h - y)) / len(y)                         
        self.weights -= self.alpha * gradient
```

EDIT - link to data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/efosler/cse5522data/master/height_vs_weight.csv

The target is whether a person plays basketball or not, and the feature I used for the single regression is height.

I'm thinking now that I do have to normalize my data anyway because I am getting some overflow with np.exp() in the multiple regression cases.

Comment: `I am worried there is a problem with my implementation.` Likely, but we can't tell since you don't show us the implementation.

Comment: @dyukha Just added the code

Comment: Would you please post (or link to) the data?

Comment: @JamesPhillips sure thing, added a link

Comment: your algorithm looks good, I would suggest few things. 1. Normalize your data (which you already considered) 2. use batch gradient descent which will reduce chance of overflow 3. Try small learning rate 4. Do scatter plot of the data see if there is some correlation or they are completely random

Comment: @DevKhadka I did a normalization between -1 and 1 for weight and height and tweaked the learning rate and I am now seeing a nice logistic curve when I plot my regression predictions, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When I make a scatterplot of Height versus Basketball, the data does not appear to lie on any type of sigmoidal or logistic curve. Based on this data set, my thought is that Height alone is insufficient to make a prediction on Basketball.

[image]